# how do you find two different characters (say N and Z) in a given words list

Tags: r

suppose this is my data frame (znot, nozzle, zean) . I expect the output be like highlighting z and n  something like that . How can I write a function in R which  goes through each word and find the characters n and z

I know there is a function called or (|) in R but no function like AND.

Comment: So in other words you have a list of strings `znot, nozzle, zean` and you want to create a function that goes through each word and find the characters `n` and `z`. What exactly do you want to do after you the matching characters?

Comment: Yes I want to create a function that goes through each word and find the characters n and z

Comment: I was more curious on what you wanted it to do after you found it

Comment: @B.Cratty Deliver the assignment probably.

Comment: @Henrik I was confused cause I didn't know if he needed to like return the index, return true or false, or what.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this?

```
pat <- c("n", "z")
x <- c("znot", "nozzle", "zean", "zebra", "nonsense")
dat <- data.frame(x)

search_letters <- function(x, pattern, ignore.case = FALSE, value = TRUE){
  i <- apply(sapply(pattern, grepl, x, ignore.case = ignore.case), 1, all)
  if(value) x[i] else i
}

search_letters(dat$x, pat)
#[1] znot   nozzle zean  
#Levels: nonsense nozzle zean zebra znot

search_letters(dat$x, pat, value = FALSE)
#[1]  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. I want the words to show up instead of true or false

Comment: @newbe Done, see now. Note that the column vector `x` is of class `factor`. This has nothing to do with the function, it has to do with how the dataframe was created. use `dat <- data.frame(x, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)` for a column of class `character`.